# convert javascript to jQuery to disable text boxes on option selection

Tags: jquery

I am currently using javascript to disable a text box if my "remote_server" option is set to no.  Here is my existing code

**HTML**

```
<select name="remote_server" class="required">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1" <?php if($remote=="1") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>Yes</option>
    <option value="0" <?php if($remote=="0") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var e = document.getElementsByName("remote_server")[0]
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if ( strUser == 0 ) {
document.getElementsByName("ftp_hostname")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("ftp_user")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("ftp_password")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("ftp_mode")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("ftp_port")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
document.getElementsByName("ftp_directory")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to jquery so that at the moment the option is chosen the text boxes will be either enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way:-

```
$('input[name=ftp_user]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

### Update:

Read more about **[prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** and **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
$('input[name^=ftp_]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('input[name^=ftp_]').prop("disabled", "disabled");​
```

OR

```
$('input[name^=ftp_]').prop("disabled", true);​
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/TpBC9/)**

Comment: use `prop()` not `attr()` for `disabled`. `prop()` was created around jQuery version 1.6 due to problems with `attr()` for properties like `disabled` that are not attributes

Comment: @charlietfl FYI `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` is perfectly all-right. (`.attr('disabled', true);` however is not)

Comment: @Tomalak   still better habit to use `prop()` for properties as stated in `attr()` docs  **To retrieve and change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.**

Comment: @charlietfl: Thanks for the valuable information. Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select[name=remote_server]').change(function(){
    var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');
    $(this).val() == "1" ? inputs.prop("disabled", "disabled") : inputs.removeProp("disabled");
});
```

Comment: that seems to be working with the exception of the selection box.  also it doesnt seem to load unless i reselect the drop down.

Comment: You didn't post all of the html.  I didn't know that one of the inputs was a select box.  Try changing `var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_]');` to `var inputs = $('input[name^=ftp_],select[name^=ftp_]');`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't seem to load".  This code should fire every time the remote_server select is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you are targeting the inputs:

`you can change to select if your html element's name belongs to html's <select> tag`

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="remote_server"]', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "1") {
       $('input[name^=ftp_]').prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
       $('input[name^=ftp_]').prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```